Connect 3rd Party VPN on AWS EC2 Ubuntu
I have subscribed a Dedicated IP of NordVPN and followed the official instructions to install necessary packages in my AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance. I normally access the instance via AWS admin console. Yet I struggled with two issues:

The terminal will always freeze when I try to execute: sudo nordvpn connect xxx where xxx is my dedicated IP's server
While I don't know why the above command fails, I manage to manually connect via openvpn command with some IP rules (Ref: Allowing SSH on a server with an active OpenVPN client). However if I do not kill / disconnect the vpn connection, I cannot SSH access my EC2 instance anymore

sudo ip rule add from $(ip route get 1 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\S+)') table 128
sudo ip route add table 128 to $(ip route get 1 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\S+)')/32 dev $(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=dev )(\S+)')
sudo ip route add table 128 default via $(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=via )(\S+)')
sudo route add -host [my EC2's elastic IP] gw [my EC2's gateway]

sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/ovpn_udp/xxx.nordvpn.com.udp.ovpn --daemon --auth-user-pass pass.txt --auth-nocache

So my question is:
Why the official command of NordVPN doesn't work as expected, and is there any way to make my EC2 instance SSH accessible even if the VPN is connected?

Are you running command #1 on your EC2 instance? If so why are you trying to connect the EC2 instance to itself,? Otherwise please clarify your question. Maybe it's formed a VPN tunnel and as such cut off your existing connection.

@Tim Yes I run all commands in a script and executed in one go on my EC2 instance. It's more like a trial and error, after I executed these scripts, I can openvpn to NordVPN. (but still failed to use official nordvpn command to connect). However, if I do not kill the VPN connection, I won't be able to SSH to my EC2 instance anymore.

Once the VPN is up it's probably not accepting connections via SSH. Instead of SSH try AWS Session Manager, which goes you a shell but works via a different method - an agent that makes an outgoing connection to the AWS endpoint.

@Tim Thanks, I will try that. If it works it solve the SSH issue, we can connect EC2 via SSH even if it connected VPN. May I know if you have any idea of the nordvpn command connection failure? I actually did talk with NordVPN support but they cannot provide any useful suggestions...

I haven't used Nord. Using a VPN from an EC2 instance is very unusual. Try session manager as I suggested.
